# Getting the screen limits from another class

Tags: c#, xna

Okay, so, I have a GameObject class, and I want this class to have an accsses to the graphics device, so I'll be able to get the Max Screen width for example. My target is to use the MaxScreen width when I create other objects who inherit from GameObject class, maybe there should be another easier way to do this thing.
If anyone haven't understood anything, I'll be glad to explain more. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the Width only, you can make a static property in the gameObject and set it in the Initialize() method.

```
class GameObject
{
    public static int ScreenWidth {get; set;}

    // bla bla
}
```

And set it like so:

```
GameObject.ScreenWidth = GraphicsDevice.DisplayMode.Width;
```

However, if you want the legit access to the GraphicsDevice, then just make a static GraphicsDevice property and set it in the initialize() method.